# HTML form disappears after updating angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have run across an interesting issue.  Recently I have decided to update angularJS to try and get it to the latest stable version.  Upon updating A form in my HTML seems to have disappeared.  It is always the first form in the HTML

```
<form name="form1"><button></button></form>
<form name="form2"></form>
```

In the above instance the object form1 no longer exists however the button is still there.  If I drop a blank form before form1 the 2 forms exist but no the empty one I just created.

I have been able to track the change down to the angular-route.js file between 1.2.4 and 1.2.5.  Any suggestions or ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to include more code before we can be helpful

Comment: You might have opened a form tag somewhere before and forgot to close it.

Comment: @KiranReddy I had been considering that.  The issue is I'm working with a Frankenstein mash-up including SharePoint and angularJS not all of which is mine.  Thus I haven't been able to find it.  Any suggestions as to how to find it?